# Dragging and dropping from browser to Nautilus saves link instead of file, how to change default action?

Tags: nautilus, firefox, drag-and-drop

When I drag and drop -- say an image -- from any internet browser to the desktop or any folder under Nautilus, it will save it as a Link.

Now if I hold down **Ctrl** while I drag and drop, it will actually save the file.

How do I swap it so that the default saves the file and I not a link?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late answer, but anyway, I'll leave this here for anyone that might want to know and finds this looking for a solution.

I solved this annoying issue by switching from nautilus (default file manager of ubuntu) to caja.

I don't understand why did the ubuntu team or nautilus team this change, but it's annoying as hell to me, I have to download a lot of images some days and put the on the right folder, so this default it's a must for me.