# Saving Gmail attachments using drag and drop results in a link, not a file

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

When I open a message in Gmail and attempt to save an attachment using the drag and drop method, (click on the file icon and drag it to a folder or the desktop) the resulting file in the destination folder is a "link", not the actual attachment.

This happens in both Firefox and Chrome browsers.

I have tried starting chrome with labs disabled (https://mail.google.com/mail/?labs=0) with no results.

OS: Ubuntu 12.04
Chrome: Version 30.0.1599.114
Firefox: Version 25.0

I'm guessing this problem is unique to my system as Googling provides no other hits on the topic.

Using the "download" link in Gmail does work fine.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

This is slowly driving me nuts. ;-)

Comment: Similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/356892/dragging-and-dropping-from-browser-to-nautilus-saves-link-instead-of-file-how-t